# How to assign variable to argument index in lambda functions?

Tags: python, lambda

I would like to know if it is possible to assign variables to the index of the arguments in `lambda` functions.

The `lambda` function is something like this. It is then used to concatenate the input matrix which is in a CasADi expression.

```
import casadi as ca 
ode = lambda x, u: ca.vertcat(x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9], x[10], 
      u[0], u[1], u[2], u[3], u[4], u[5])
```

My goal is to replace the indexing with a variable or maybe assign the lambda arguments in a recursive way so I will not have a long line of `lambda` function with its arguments indexing.

Comment: `ca.vertcat(*x[6:11], *u[0:6])`

Comment: You could then use variables in the slice indexes.

Comment: More generally, `ca.vertcat(*foo(x), *bar(u))`, where `foo = operator.itemgetter(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)` and `bar = operator.itemgetter(0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5)`. `itemgetter` takes arbitrary indices; they don't need to be in any particular order, but the order of the results matches the order of the arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for your reply! I will try this out. But I wasn't sure the slicing indexes is supported in the CasADi expression (an external package), as the lambda arguments would be a CasADi expression.

Comment: Argument processing is basic Python syntax, it has nothing to do with the function you're calling.

Comment: Thanks @chepner! This is the generic approach I expected. So the ```itemgetter``` receive only exact items like in the example (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) instead of a variable or an index range?

Comment: You can use variables for the arguments to `itemgetter` the same as you are using the result of `itemgetter` as the arguments to `ca.vertcat`. It's not clear where or how you want to supply these indices though, so it's hard to suggest a solution. Maybe `lambda x, u, xis, uis: ca.vertcat(*itemgetter(*xis)(x), *itemgetter(*uis)(u))`? That would allow, for example, `ode(some_xs, some_us, (6,7,8,9,10), (0,1,2,3,4,5))`.

Comment: However, it might be simpler to just pass the correct slice or elements to `ode` in the first place, rather than pass the collection and the indices separately.